# angular cannot set property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an error in angular js, when setting application.apikey with response.data.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label>1:</label>

        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apikey" ng-model="applicationn.apikey"></input>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label>2:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apikeysecret" ng-model="application.apisecret"></input>
    </div>
</div>
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.getApiKey = function () {
            $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/applications/generateApiKey'
        }).then(function success(response) {
            console.log(response.data),
            $scope.application.apikey = response.data.apikey;
        });
    }
```

Console:

```
    {id: null, name: null, apikey: "cce4866e0b23c721b1e8d733a4cf48c1", apisecret: "914c87f20473c4fac9fbbab65de6e6b0", custom_data: null}
angular.js:14525 TypeError: Cannot set property 'apikey' of undefined
```

Comment: you probably need to parse the response with `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: try `$scope.application={ apikey : response.data.apikey}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined `$scope.application` and trying to define its property.

Try this :

```
$scope.application = {};
$scope.getApiKey = function () {
            $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/applications/generateApiKey'
        }).then(function success(response) {
            console.log(response.data),
            $scope.application.apikey = response.data.apikey;
        });
    }
```

Comment: thanks, so if i get it right, everytime i declare variable in html file, i must declare it in controller too?

Comment: no its not necessary, the problem was, you used $scope.application.apikey without defining $scope.application, you could have used $scope.apikey without defining anything